# AWS ECS error in prisma container - environment variable PRISMA_CONFIG

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, amazon-ecs, prisma

I'm new to AWS, and I'm trying to deploy my local web app on AWS using ECR and ECS, but got stuck when running a cluster, it throws the error about the PRISMA_CONFIG environment variable in prisma container.

In my local environment, i'm using docker to build the app using nodejs, prisma and mongodb, it's working fine.

Now on ECS, i created a task definition and for prisma container, i tried to copy the yml config from my local docker-compose.yml file to make it work.

There is field called "ENVIRONMENT", I've inputted the value in the Environment variables, it's just not working and throw the error while the cluster was running, then the task Stopped.

the yml is in multiple lines, but the input box supports string only

the variable key is PRISMA_CONFIG
and the following are the values that i've already tried

```
| port: 4466\n databases:\n default:\n connector: mongo\n uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo\n
```

```
| \nport: 4466 \ndatabases: \ndefault: \nconnector: mongo \nuri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo
```

```
|\nport: 4466\n databases:\n default:\n connector: mongo\n uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo
```

```
\nport: 4466\n databases:\n default:\n connector: mongo\n uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo
```

```
port: 4466\n databases:\n default:\n connector: mongo\n uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo\n
```

and the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid Prisma config could be loaded.
```

```
expected a comment or a line break, but found p(112)
```

```
expected chomping or indentation indicators, but found \(92)
```

i expected that all containers will run without errors, but actual results are the container stopped after running for a minute.

Please help for this.
or suggest other way to deploy to AWS?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: If your setup in AWS allows you to add config files you could also pass in a yml config file and refer to it in your compose file in the PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. The following tutorial is for Dokku deployment but may have useful information for anyone running into this problem or something similar. It describes the use of Prisma's PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH environment variable: https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/deploy-prisma-to-dokku-ct15

Comment: looks good as well !!, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking for a similar solution to load the prisma config without the multiline string.

There are repositories that load the prisma environment variables separately without a prisma config:

Check out this repo for example:
https://github.com/akoenig/prisma-docker-compose/blob/master/.prisma.env

Here akoenig uses the following env variables using a env_file. So, I'm assuming you can just pass in these environment variables separately to achieve what prisma is looking for.

```
# CONTENTS OF env_file

PORT=4466
SQL_CLIENT_HOST_CLIENT1=database
SQL_CLIENT_HOST_READONLY_CLIENT1=database
SQL_CLIENT_HOST=database
SQL_CLIENT_PORT=3306
SQL_CLIENT_USER=root
SQL_CLIENT_PASSWORD=prisma
SQL_CLIENT_CONNECTION_LIMIT=10
SQL_INTERNAL_HOST=database
SQL_INTERNAL_PORT=3306
SQL_INTERNAL_USER=root
SQL_INTERNAL_PASSWORD=prisma
SQL_INTERNAL_DATABASE=graphcool
CLUSTER_ADDRESS=http://prisma:4466
SQL_INTERNAL_CONNECTION_LIMIT=10
SCHEMA_MANAGER_SECRET=graphcool
SCHEMA_MANAGER_ENDPOINT=http://prisma:4466/cluster/schema
#CLUSTER_PUBLIC_KEY=
BUGSNAG_API_KEY=""
ENABLE_METRICS=0
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1G
```

This is for a mySQL database. You would need to tailor this to suit your values. But in theory you should just be able to pass these variables one by one into single variables in AWS's GUI.

I've also asked this question on the Prisma Slack channel and am waiting to see if they have other suggestions: https://prisma.slack.com/archives/CA491RJH0/p1569689413383000

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Not and expert here but, have you set up an environment variable PRISMA_API_MANAGEMENT_SECRET you would have defined the secret when you configured your fargate instance.

have a look at the following artical

https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/deploy-prisma-to-aws-fargate-ct14